# Entering Zip Code Switchies View Controller If Found In Parse (Swift and XCode)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, zipcode

So I'm trying to create a registration page with availability by Zip Code.
For instance, a user can only register if the service is available in their area (zip code).

So far I have a Text field for Zip Code and a button labeled "Check Availability".

I have a Parse Backend and I tested a connection to it using their setup guide and it works.

How can I go about adding Zip Codes to Parse and when a user types in that zip code that matches it'll open a new View Controller and they can register.

Comment: so i understand you want to save the zip code to parse then check if the input zipped code is found into parse

Comment: check out my answer hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

First method is to save zipCode that the user entered from the TextField:

```
var zipcodeFromUsers = customTextfield.text.toInt()
var savingObject = PFObject(className: "nameoftheclass")
savingObject["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
savingObject["zipcode"]  = zipcodeFromUsers
savingObject.saveEventually { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
      // data was saved
    }
}
```

Second Method is to retrieve all the zipcodes from parse. So lets say that we want to query all 2344 zip codes

```
var needToFoundZipcode = 2344
var queryFromParse = PFQuery(className: "nameoftheclass")
queryFromParse.whereKey("zipcode", equalTo: needToFoundZipcode)
queryFromParse.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
        {
            for SingleZipcode in objects
            {

                var singlezipcodeFound = SingleZipcode["zipcode"] as! Int

                // now you could whatever you want

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can this work if there is no user logged in? And after clicking the "Check Availibility" button it should either say not available in this region or if it is available it will direct the user to a register/signup page.

Comment: I want to add the zip codes on my own into parse using a JSON import file and have the user type in a zip code and see if it matches the one I put into parse myself.

Comment: so i think what you should do is too query all data from JSON then data you take the user zip code then compare them if they equal you save them

Comment: Okay, so the first method wouldn't be necessary correct?